# XCode 4.3.2 Settings.bundle missing files

Tags: xcode, settings

Env: XCode 4.3.2, IOS 5.1

I am trying to add a setting.bundle for my project.

```
File->New->File->IOS Resource->Setting.bundle->Next->Create
```

There are no files in this bundle. I tried "cd" in the terminal, but I still cannot see anything — it is an empty directory.

There should be 3 files and 1 directory in the bundle.  Can anyone please tell me why I am missing all these files, or has Apple changed the concept for settings.bundle or something?

I tried this with several my projects and even re-installed xcode and lion, no luck at all.

P.S: Changing the file type for the setting.bundle does not help; no such option in 4.3.2.

Comment: Hi, Using finder are you able to right click on it and use "show package contents" ?

Comment: Thanks for your comment, man. there are no files in the package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A clean install solved this issue.